# How to create an outputSettings Dictionary<String. Any> for use with an AVAssetWriterInput instance?

Tags: avfoundation, swift3, avassetwriter, avassetwriterinput

I am attempting to convert a MPMediaItem instance into a caf formatted audio file. I have been following the work of Chris Adamson and his post on [From iPod Library to PCM Samples in Far Fewer Steps Than Were Previously Necessary](http://subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/)

As I was digging around looking how to do this in swift I came across 
Abel Domingues github [FileConverter.swift](https://gist.github.com/abeldomingues/fe8fa797fd55603f2f4a) for doing just this in Swift.

I then set about converting to Swift 3 as an extension to protocol.
All went well until I try to run it it. It crashes on the `assetWriterInput` object creation and seems to be related to the `outputSettings` variable.

```
        var outputSettings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
            AVChannelLayoutKey: NSData(bytes:&channelLayout, length:MemoryLayout<AudioChannelLayout>.size),
            AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
            AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: false,
            AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
            AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false
        ] as [String : Any]

        // create an asset writer input
        let assetWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio, outputSettings:outputSettings as NSDictionary as! [String : Any])
```

The error message I receive is the following:

`-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1704407b0
2016-10-13 18:34:52.032784 Testie[3098:1535938] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue unsignedIntValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1704407b0'`

I have searched for examples of this, but must posts are in Objective-C and/or related to setting up the dictionary for video.

This is the documentation from the AVAssetWriterInput source related to audio:

> For AVMediaTypeAudio the following keys are not currently supported in
>   the outputSettings dictionary: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey and
>   AVSampleRateConverterAudioQualityKey.  When using this initializer, an
>   audio settings dictionary must be fully specified, meaning that it
>   must contain AVFormatIDKey, AVSampleRateKey, and
>   AVNumberOfChannelsKey.  If no other channel layout information is
>   available, a value of 1 for AVNumberOfChannelsKey will result in mono
>   output and a value of 2 will result in stereo output.  If
>   AVNumberOfChannelsKey specifies a channel count greater than 2, the
>   dictionary must also specify a value for AVChannelLayoutKey.  For
>   kAudioFormatLinearPCM, all relevant AVLinearPCM*Key keys must be
>   included, and for kAudioFormatAppleLossless, AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey
>   keys must be included.  See
>   -initWithMediaType:outputSettings:sourceFormatHint: for a way to avoid having to specify a value for each of those keys.

So what in the dictionary is causing the error?

Comment: I can post more code, I just did not want to drown the the question out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift 3, `kAudioFormatLinearPCM` is imported as `UInt32` (aka `AudioFormatID`), and Swift 3.0.0 cannot convert it to an appropriate type (`NSNumber` in this case) when put in `[String: Any]`.

Try this:

```
    var outputSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey: UInt(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVChannelLayoutKey: NSData(bytes:&channelLayout, length:MemoryLayout<AudioChannelLayout>.size),
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
        AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: false,
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
        AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false
    ] as [String : Any]
```

Or wait till Xcode 8.1/Swift 3.0.1, which should fix your case.